# jQuery ajax call only from HTML page

Tags: jquery, ajax

Given the following jQuery code that makes an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

The problem I have is that the user could manually enter test.html on the URL and see the response on the screen. How to avoid that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437747/how-to-hide-details-in-jquery-ajax-from-browser-page-source)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow access to PHP file only through ajax on local server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436948/allow-access-to-php-file-only-through-ajax-on-local-server)

Comment: First of all, you must have some server side language in order to control those things. If you have PHP, the post suggested by @bill is indeed a duplicate. Otherwise, tell what language you do have, and someone might guide you how to adapt the code for that language.

Comment: I use scala on the server side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you an do this to create a variable for in some other script or location so the user will only see the variable name.

Also send you request through post method and make you server ajax reponse page respond to POST request only( say using some server side language like PHP, ASP.Net or JSP). This way even if the user find out the path of the url it will not be able to view its contents.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding some kind of authorization in the `HTTP header`. Use the Ajax `beforeSend` setting. Then authenticate the header with PHP or any other server side language.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, AJAX calls are basically just HTTP calls and can be access with direct browsing.